# I'm having issues using a text input to search through an array for an object with a particular property in an Express app

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, express, object

I am trying to setup a function in my Express app to help the user find an employee (object) that is stored in a Mongo Database, by using the data from a text input.

I'm hoping that once the user has pressed the <kbd>submit</kbd> button, if the text input data is included in one of the names in the database, it will link to an ejs page with the matching person's info.

At the moment I am getting the following error message when I run my code.

```
Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

My function looks like this

```javascript
const searchEmployees = wrapAsync(async(req, res, next) => {
    const info = req.query.searchEmployees;
    const employee = await Employee.find({});
    if (employee.firstName.includes(info)) {
        res.render('employees/search', { employee });
    } else {
        res.render('No match found')
    }

})
```

Perhaps someone can help?

Many thanks

Comment: I'm a javascript noob, but won't `employee` be an array?  Maybe `employee.some(doc => doc.firstName.includes(info))` might work?  Ultimately, you should let the MongoDB server do the work with something like `Employee.find({firstName: {$regex: info}})`.

Comment: `res.render('employees/search', { employee });` will return the entire `Employee` collection.  Is that really what you want to present?

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your feedback! Yes I believe you are correct, employee will be an array. I'm not familiar with the $regex: info approach. I will take a look at it.

Comment: No I don't want to return the entire employee array, I would like to return any employee objects from the array that contain the information that the user inputs into the text input.